# How to replace hover in to on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a full-width menu, which currently works on hover. I want the exact same functionality but on click not on mouseover.  I want to use some jQuery or JavaScript only to achieve this functionality.

Here is the code

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #bebebe;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
  position:relative;
}
nav ul {
  background: #bebebe;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0 20px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
  color:#333333;
  display:block;
  padding:0px 40px;
  text-decoration:none;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
   line-height: 60px;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background: #333333;
}
nav ul li:hover > a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}
nav ul ul {
  background: #BEBEBE;
  padding:0;
  text-align: center;
  display:none;
    width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

If you want to see this in action here is the link. 
[Please click here to see the menu in action](https://jsfiddle.net/ziakhan/8uj1u2rd/1/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/17638990/590373

Comment: I checked this answer. This is totally different for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution:

I have fork your jsfiddle with updated code. Please take a look

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

nav {
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #bebebe;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
  position:relative;
}
nav ul {
  background: #bebebe;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0 20px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
  color:#333333;
  display:block;
  padding:0px 40px;
  text-decoration:none;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
   line-height: 60px;
}
/*nav ul li:hover {
  background: #333333;
}
nav ul li:hover > a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}*/
nav ul ul {
  background: #BEBEBE;
  padding:0;
  text-align: center;
  display:none;
    width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0px;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').on('click',function(){
        $(this).siblings('li').not(this).find('a').css('color','#333333');
        $(this).siblings('li').not(this).find('ul').css('display','none');
        $(this).siblings('li').not(this).css('background','#BEBEBE');
        $(this).find('a').css('color','#FFFFFF');
        $(this).find('ul').css('display','block');
        $(this).css('background','#333333');
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/304g4yw5/)

Comment: It stull have issue. If you apply it on this link http://jsfiddle.net/c5ghc80s/8/ , It did not work fine.

Comment: What is this @user3144924, this is not your code posted with question.

Comment: Bro this is dynamic menu generated from XML, That is wasy I can not add many classed. I need to do all with jquery or javascript.

Comment: Oh, in that case, how can we give solution if html code is not in a specific structure.

Comment: I edit everything for you. I used your logic and we are very near. Here you will see subject, if you click on subject it will show you English and Maths but if you click on English it not go to english details. Here is link to http://jsfiddle.net/ziakhan/c5ghc80s/9/

Comment: Thanks, man. I used your logic and it works for me. Can you please check the jsfiddle. I used exactly your logic. I did little bit changes. $(this).children('ul').css('display','block'); added this/  Here is the updated link. http://jsfiddle.net/ziakhan/c5ghc80s/11/

Comment: Your welcome @user3144924, happy to help. Thanks for up vote and accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following CSS rules

```
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}
```

with

```
nav ul li.expanded > ul {
  display:block;
}
```

Now, you can handle a click on a menu item and remove/add the `expanded` CSS class to expand the item:

```
function handle(){
    $("nav ul li").on("click", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        var parent = $(this).parent("li");
        if (parent.length)
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("expanded");
        else
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("expanded");
        $(this).addClass("expanded")
  });
}
```

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytrr3hbw/).

Comment: Thank you, it is working on first child node but unfortunately not of sub-node on child nod. If you click on Subjects it show English, but if we click on English it does not show English A and English B. Here you can check http://jsfiddle.net/ziakhan/c5ghc80s/9/

Comment: I've updated my answer. See the new JS code and fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace your `:hover` styles with `.expanded`,
2. Add `expanded` class to your `<li>` elements containing the *expandable* `<ul>`
3. Also, add `close-expanded` to not expandable menu items, so clicking them will close the last clicked expanded element.
4. In your jQuery, add class `expanded` to the clicked `expandable` element.
5. In your jQuery, remove class `expanded` from every `expandable` element when `close-expandable` is clicked.

```js
$(".expandable").on("click", function(event) {

  $(".expanded").removeClass("expanded");
  $(this).addClass("expanded");

});

$(".close-expanded").on("click", function(event) {

  $(".expanded").removeClass("expanded");
  
});
```

```css
nav {
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
  background: #bebebe;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
  position:relative;
}
nav ul {
  background: #bebebe;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0 20px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 60px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
  color:#333333;
  display:block;
  padding:0px 40px;
  text-decoration:none;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
   line-height: 60px;
}
nav ul li.expanded { /* replaced :hover with .expanded */
  background: #333333;
}
nav ul li.expanded > a{ /* replaced :hover with .expanded */
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
nav ul li.expanded > ul { /* replaced :hover with .expanded */
  display:block;
}
nav ul ul {
  background: #BEBEBE;
  padding:0;
  text-align: center;
  display:none;
    width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="close-expanded"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="expandable"><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="expandable"><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="close-expanded"><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8uj1u2rd/3/)**.

You could combine `children()` and `toggle()` like :

```
$('ul>li').on('click',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();

  $(this).children('ul').toggle();
})
```

Make sure to add `e.stopPropagation()` to stop event from bubbling.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you extend the menu with the sub nodes then it creates problems. https://jsfiddle.net/ziakhan/8uj1u2rd/4/